# MongoDB find $in

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I am trying to look on the field:

```
[case-file-header] => Array (
                      [filing-date] => 20130111)
```

like this:

```
$cursor = $mongo->$db->$collection->find(array('case-file-header'=>
                                                     array('filing-date' => 
                                                                 array('$in' => array($current_date)))));
```

what am I doing wrong?

My collection consists of 7 million records. Here's an example of one record:

```
[_id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 50f5a5630c7263b79a373390
)
[serial-number] => 76713205
[registration-number] => 0000000
[transaction-date] => 20130114
[case-file-header] => Array (
   [filing-date] => 20130111
   [status-code] => 630
   [status-date] => 20130114
   [mark-identification] => ALPHACHEMICAL
   [mark-drawing-code] => 3000
   [attorney-docket-number] => 113,328
   [attorney-name] => William Nitkin
   [principal-register-amended-in] => F
   [supplemental-register-amended-in] => F
   [trademark-in] => T
   [collective-trademark-in] => F
   [service-mark-in] => F
   [collective-service-mark-in] => F
   [collective-membership-mark-in] => F
   [certification-mark-in] => F
 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really use the positional operator instead since MongoDB will actually try something else when you make nesting like:

```
array('case-file-header'=>
array('filing-date' =>
```

So:

```
$mongo->$db->$collection->find(array(
    'case-file-header.filing-date' => array('$in' => array($current_date))
));
```

Should work

This is an exact sample that works with the doc you showed:

```
$mongo = new Mongo();
$db = $mongo->mydb;

$current_date = 20130111;

$db->some_test_collection->insert(array(
    '_id' => new MongoId('50f5a5630c7263b79a373390'),
    'serial-number' => 76713205,
    'registration-number' => 0000000,
    'transaction-date' => 20130114,
    'case-file-header' => Array(
       'filing-date' => 20130111,
       'status-code' => 630,
       'status-date' => 20130114,
       'mark-identification' => 'ALPHACHEMICAL',
       'mark-drawing-code' => 3000,
       'attorney-docket-number' => '113,328',
       'attorney-name' => 'William Nitkin',
       'principal-register-amended-in' => 'F',
       'supplemental-register-amended-in' => 'F',
       'trademark-in' => 'T',
       'collective-trademark-in' => 'F',
       'service-mark-in' => 'F',
       'collective-service-mark-in' => 'F',
       'collective-membership-mark-in' => 'F',
       'certification-mark-in' => 'F'
    )
));
$cursor = $db->some_test_collection->find(array('case-file-header.filing-date' => array('$in' => array($current_date))));
foreach($cursor as $row) var_dump($row);
var_dump($cursor->count());
exit();
```

With the output being:

```
int 1

array
  '_id' => 
    object(MongoId)[5]
      public '$id' => string '50f5a5630c7263b79a373390' (length=24)
  'serial-number' => int 76713205
  'registration-number' => int 0
  'transaction-date' => int 20130114
  'case-file-header' => 
    array
      'filing-date' => int 20130111
      'status-code' => int 630
      'status-date' => int 20130114
      'mark-identification' => string 'ALPHACHEMICAL' (length=13)
      'mark-drawing-code' => int 3000
      'attorney-docket-number' => string '113,328' (length=7)
      'attorney-name' => string 'William Nitkin' (length=14)
      'principal-register-amended-in' => string 'F' (length=1)
      'supplemental-register-amended-in' => string 'F' (length=1)
      'trademark-in' => string 'T' (length=1)
      'collective-trademark-in' => string 'F' (length=1)
      'service-mark-in' => string 'F' (length=1)
      'collective-service-mark-in' => string 'F' (length=1)
      'collective-membership-mark-in' => string 'F' (length=1)
      'certification-mark-in' => string 'F' (length=1)
```

So there must be something else wrong somewhere

Comment: @EugenShevchuk Hmm how many elements are you querying? You might need an index on that field

Comment: do not know. about a thousand. now try with index. 
this may be due to incorrect query?

Comment: @EugenShevchuk Nah a timeout occurs when the cursor timeouts before it can return a result

Comment: Creates an index on the field - the same

Comment: @EugenShevchuk Can you paste an example of your document in your question, I'll test this myself

Comment: foreach ($cursor as $doc) {} - in the cycle, I'm trying to get the information I needed - but nothing happens. probably because the query does not return records

Comment: @EugenShevchuk Possibly but it is hard for me to really comment without seeing a sample document. Can you edit your question with a sample (taken straight from the db on your end, of course change info that might be sensitive) and I will test it with what I have got.

Comment: I edited my question. and after the request - $cursor->count() has shown 0

Comment: @EugenShevchuk Check my edit, I can't seem to replicate the problem using the example you showed, there must be something else somewhere causing the problem

Comment: very strange. if we look for the field "serial number" - all finds. and on case-file-header.filing-date - nothing

Comment: @EugenShevchuk I have just thought, the dump you showed above did not show the field type (i.e. string or int) I assumed int in my example code, can you try querying by both string and int for `$currentdate` and see if one returns the right result?

Comment: it worked, found all records) I tried it with string. thnak you for help!;)

Comment: I have a field "filing-date = 20130111". is it possible to search for the first 4 characters, the year - 2013? maybe there is a mask? like: "array('$in' => array('2013****'))"

Comment: @EugenShevchuk Yea you can do a regex but not within a $in instead you do: `$db->col->find(array('filing-date' => new MongoRegex('/^2013/')))` note that regex can be slow